# Ember CLI with Multiple Proxies

Tags: proxy, ember-cli

**The Problem:**

I have an Ember CLI Application that will consume multiple APIs, which I need to proxy to in development mode.

**Background:**

I have a legacy api which exposes services at `/api` running on my local development machine at `localhost:3000`

I have a new api which exposes services at `/myapp/api/v1`. These services were recently extracted from the legacy app, and comprises the majority of the application services used by the ember app.

The ember app uses the baseURL of `/myapp`, as it is being deployed to a subdirectory.

I generated two http-proxys using `ember generate http-proxy`. They are located at `/server/proxies/api.js` and `server/proxies/myapp/api/v1.js`

api.js

```
var proxyPath = '/api';
module.exports = function(app) {
  var proxy = require('http-proxy').createProxyServer({});
  proxy.on('error', function(err, req) {
    console.error(err, req.url);
  });
  app.use(proxyPath, function(req, res, next){
    // include root path in proxied request
    req.url = proxyPath + '/' + req.url;
    proxy.web(req, res, { target: 'http://localhost:3000' });
  });
};
```

myapp/api/v1.js

```
var proxyPath = 'myapp/api/v1';
module.exports = function(app) {
  var proxy = require('http-proxy').createProxyServer({});
  proxy.on('error', function(err, req) {
    console.error(err, req.url);
  });
  app.use(proxyPath, function(req, res, next){
    req.url = proxyPath + '/' + req.url;
    proxy.web(req, res, { target: 'http://localhost:4100' });
  });
};
```

The first proxy, to /api, appears to be working, the second API, to /myapp/api/v1/whatever fails.

It doesn't appear to be used or considered. When I run , for instance a POST to myapp/api/v1/sessions, it just says cannot POST. When I put debugger on the proxy.on and app.use functions, they are never hit.

Where am I going wrong here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
var proxyPath = 'myapp/api/v1';
```

You're missing a `/` in the beginning of the string ;)

Comment: FYI, I didn't post the bounty, so it'll be up to @Asherlc to award it :)