# How can I get my app (running via ng serve) to connect to a Node back-end while preserving the auto-reload functionality?

Tags: angular, angular2-cli

I've just migrated my application to Angular CLI. I already have my REST API Node server up and running. I would like to be able to run my front-end with `ng serve`, to have the auto-reload feature every time I change a file, but also have it connect to my node back-end.

Livereload server is running on port 49152
Serving on port 4200
Node listening on port 8080

All my node routes are prefixed with `api`.

Is this possible?

Comment: What precisely doesn't work?  I've done this before with a tomcat server and no issues.  I'm not sure how a node server would change anything.

Comment: Well, if my angular app is being served by the development server on port 4200, any back-end API requests will also be sent to port 4200.  How could I have 2 servers listening to the same port? Theoretically I could change my services to call the back-end on a different port but that would be a pain, besides breaking the same origin policy.

Comment: Ok, I see your problem now.  Yes, in the past I used to solve this with the grunt server by setting up a proxy (the grunt server would proxy all requests that didn't match a front-end static resource).  It looks like there is a [request](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/889) for such a feature in angular-cli but it hasn't been implemented yet.  You may also look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37172928/angular-cli-server-how-to-proxy-api-requests-to-another-server).

Comment: I got some helpful pointers in the first link you mentioned. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So because a formal answer hasn't been submitted for this, I'll give it a shot.
Say you have your node powered api running on 8080. You can get that started in one terminal/cmd window with your typical `node server.js` command. Then, in the same project folder, the same one you have your `package.json` you will want to add a `proxy-config.json` file with the following content

```
{
    "/api": { // or whatever your endpoint is in your api routes
        "target": "http://localhost:8080", // your node server.js api
        "secure": false
    }
}
```

Then you can start your project with `ng serve --proxy proxy-config.json`.

Docs: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/master/docs/documentation/stories/proxy.md

Comment: Superb solution @gh0st. I have been looking for this solution since 5 hours! Thanks a lot! :)