# How to enable CORS when sending http post request from Angular2 app

Tags: angular, firebase, xmlhttprequest, cors

When I tried to send http request, I got this error about CORS.

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load 'sever-domain'. 
Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. 
Origin 'my-firebsase-hosted-app-domain' is therefore not allowed access.
```

Then I set headers to my http request like this.

```
let headers = new Headers(
  {
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
   }
);
let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
this.postRequestSub = this._http.post(this.url, body, options);
```

But I still have the same error, isn't this a correct way to solve it?

Comment: CORS needs to be configured on the server. Angular is not involved in that.

Comment: You can use proxy to handle it on client side. https://webpack.github.io/docs/webpack-dev-server.html#proxy

Comment: Thank you for answering me soon. You mean I can handle this error by correctly setting proxy like this, right? [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37172928/angular-cli-server-how-to-proxy-api-requests-to-another-server)

Answer (score 3):

As Günter Zöchbauer commented,

> CORS needs to be configured on the server

Here is a link which will help you get started [Enable CORS](https://enable-cors.org/server.html).

Comment: Thank you! I'll check this link.