# Angular - Connects to Proxy server and gets response but then shows Error occured while trying to proxy to: localhost to actual server

Tags: angular, angular-cli, econnreset

I'm new to Angular(2,4). I was trying to connect to proxy server.

Added `proxy.config.json` in project root directory

```
{
    "/api/*": {
        "target": "http://<server_ip_address>:<port>",
        "secure": false,
        "changeOrigin": true,
        "logLevel": "debug"
    }
}
```

Then added the proxy config in `start` in package.json

```
"scripts": {
        "ng": "ng",
        "start": "ng serve --proxy-config proxy.config.json",
        "build": "ng build",
        "test": "ng test",
        "lint": "ng lint",
        "e2e": "ng e2e"
    },
```

Now in component I have a login method to connect to server.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

import { AlertService, AuthenticationService } from '../services/index';

@Component({
    moduleId: module.id.toString(),
    templateUrl: 'login.component.html'
})

export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
    model: any = {};
    loading = false;
    returnUrl: string;

    constructor(
        private route: ActivatedRoute,
        private router: Router,
        private authenticationService: AuthenticationService,
        private alertService: AlertService) { }

    login() {
            this.loading = true;
            this.authenticationService.login(this.model.email, this.model.password)
                .subscribe(data => {
                    localStorage.setItem('currentUser', JSON.stringify(data));
                    this.router.navigate([this.returnUrl]);
                },
                error => {
                    this.alertService.error(error);
                    this.loading = false;
                },
                () => {
                    console.log("Subscribed Else");
                });
        }
}
```

In Authentication Service I have following code.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Headers, Response } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/throw';


@Injectable()
export class AuthenticationService {
    headers = new Headers();

    constructor(private http: Http) {
        this.headers.append("Content-Type", "application/json");
    }

    login(email: string, password: string) {
        return this.http.post('/api/v1/login', { email: email, password: password }, { headers: this.headers })
            .map(this.extractData)
            .catch(this.handleError);
    }

    private extractData(response: Response) {
        let user = response.json();
        return user;
    }
    private handleError(error: Response | any) {
        // In a real world app, you might use a remote logging infrastructure
        let errMsg: string;
        let resMsg: string;
        if (error instanceof Response) {
            const body = error.json() || '';
            resMsg = body['message'];
            console.log(body);
            console.log(resMsg);
        } else {
            resMsg = error.message ? error.message : error.toString();
        }
        return Observable.throw(resMsg);
    }
}
```

The connection works fine. The server responds with proper JSON data. But I would be able t login.

**Real Problem**

It''s weird. Sometimes it works fine, but mostly it shows issue even after connecting to server properly. The server responds with JSON data. Then in terminal console it shows

**[HPM] Error occurred while trying to proxy request /api/v1/login from localhost:4200 to http://: (ECONNRESET) (https
                ://nodejs.org/api/errors.html#errors_common_system_errors)**

If I check the chrome network console, the status of request is **OK.** But in the preview tab, it shows JSON from server and then it appends with following string "Error occured while trying to proxy to: localhost:4200/api/v1/login"

```
{"name":"something","id":"12sde"}Error occured while trying to proxy to: localhost:4200/api/v1/login
```

Because of that JSON parsing gets error.

Why issue happens sometimes and not always? And what's the actual issue?

**P.S.**: I'm using angular - 4.0.0, angular-cli 1.0.2

Comment: so the error happens because of invalid JSON.

Comment: Parse error happens because of JSON. But issue with connection I guess

Comment: Probably your back-end gives not a json response. May be it is not ready to serve request - restarting?

Comment: try to send requests with some other tool (postman, curl) and verify result

Comment: Hey @iCode, did you solve it. I have same issue

Answer (score 2):

Downgrading my node version from the current version to the recommended version helped me with a similar issue.

Comment: Thanks. More me upgrading to node v18.17.0 worked

Answer (score 1):

When you are using the Angular CLI, you are using the Webpack Dev Server : [Link to their Github.](https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server) All you are doing is passing the path to your proxy file into the CLI, which then downloads it and passes it into webpack-dev-server.

On [this issue](https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server/issues/424), it's reported that removing the * in "/api/*" might fix your problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
try to add "Connection": "keep-alive" to your proxy.config.json like mentioned below

{
    "/api/*": {
        "target": "http://<server_ip_address>:<port>",
        "secure": false,
        "changeOrigin": true,
        "logLevel": "debug",
        "headers": {
            "Connection": "keep-alive"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

I also had this problem, finally I add a function to filter the response:

```
private parseResponse(response) {
   return JSON.parse(response['_body'].replace(/}Error.*/, '}'))
}
```

Here are some refs:

https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-proxy

https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/889#issuecomment-290112673

Hope you could find a better solution

---

use [HttpClient](https://angular.io/guide/http) instead of Http

Comment: this is no real way of fixing the problem, it just addresses the symptoms. also, using HttpClient is no solution. (i'm having these problems regardless)