# Angular Frontend and proxy to wildlfy rest service

Tags: angular, proxy, wildfly

I have an angular frontend that uses rest services provided by wildfly. To call the wildfly from angular I installed a proxy using this informations:
[angular-cli server - how to proxy API requests to another server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37172928/angular-cli-server-how-to-proxy-api-requests-to-another-server)

When I now call the service from my angular app, I get the following error in wildfly.
javax.ws.rs.NotFoundException: Could not find resource for full path: http://localhost:8080/whatever/rest/entity

Calling the url in the browser works fine.

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Now I found the solution:

proxy.config.json

```
{
   "/**api**": {
      "target": "http://localhost:8080/whatever/rest",
      "secure": false,
      "changeOrigin": true
   }
}
```

this way the proxy forwards you to http://localhost:8080/whatever/rest/api/entity

I thought api isn't regarded.

So I changed it like this:

```
{
   "/**rest**": {
      "target": "http://localhost:8080/whatever/",
      "secure": false,
      "changeOrigin": true
   }
}
```

and it worked. The url http://localhost:8080/whatever/rest/entity is reachable

Answer (score 0):

Just a suggestion, it could be that your missing a trailing slash at the end.

Comment: Thanks, but didn't help: javax.ws.rs.NotFoundException: Could not find resource for full path: http://localhost:8080/whatever/rest/entity/