# Angular 4 http patch not working with call but works with postman

Tags: angular, http, typescript

I am trying to make a patch/and post call to the server but it never gets to the server. I have tried doing this with postman and it works there. so I'm pretty sure its something with my code.

Basically, my post and patch are the same so i will only show the patch.

```
protected patch(url: string, body: any): Observable<any> {
    let options = this.getRequestOptions(body);
    return this.http.patch(this.baseUrl+url,JSON.stringify(body),options);
}
private getRequestOptions(body:any):RequestOptions{
    let cpHeaders = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: cpHeaders });

    return options;
}
```

please note that `this.baseUrl = "http://localhost/blah/api/` and url is being passed in as `test`;

I would appreciate any help here. thanks in advance

**Update**

```
   [HttpPut]
    public virtual IHttpActionResult Patch([FromBody]T entity)
    {
        return Ok(_repository.Patch(entity));
    }

    [HttpPatch]
    public virtual IHttpActionResult WebPatch([FromBody]T entity)
    {
        return this.Patch(entity);
    }
```

I have a proxy config as subjected in comments below.

```
 {
  "/api": {
    "target": "http://localhost/QuickQuoteApi",
    "secure": false,
    "pathRewrite": {
      "^/api": ""
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What is your backend?

Comment: I am using web api, written in c#

Comment: Sorry I meant what language is the API written in? And could you post a snippet of the backend?

Comment: If using Angular CLI include your proxy config. If you haven't edited your proxy config to include 'blah' route and you're not using `ng serve -pc proxy.conf.js` that's the likely problem

Comment: @Z.Bagley can you please explain? I am using Angular Cli. I will say that the get request works correctly

Comment: More or less you need to incorporate a proxy config file when using http in an angular environment as shown in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/39715785/7733570

Comment: in your case in the proxy config `"/api"` should be `"/blah/api"`

Answer (score 13):

*Late response, but useful for future developers.*

I had the same issue, it worked in Postman but not in Angular.

Since the patch object is an observable, you must subscribe for it to invoke the patch call.

```
this.patch(url, payload).subscribe(); // Executes path object
```