# Is it good practice to define your API in the Angular-Universal Server?

Tags: angular, server-side-rendering, angular-universal, angular5

As i was developing my Angular Universal app i realised that the development of the API-Functions (like Authentication, Sending and Receiving Data) on the Server for the Rendering of the Universal app is exhausting.
The App needs to be packed and restarted everytime i change something.

**Am i supposed to do this Implementation on another "Server" ?**

I would suggest implementing an own node-server (for example with different port number) with all those functions.

Is this the default behaviour ?

I am thankful for every suggestion on how to improve the development procedure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the best practice is not using a web universal app for those tasks.

To avoid this:

"The App needs to be packed and restarted everytime i change something."

If you want to use your api with your angular app without compiling to get a `dist/` directory. Take a peek to set up a config.proxy file on angular. It's quite easy!!

**Angular Proxy:**

https://stackoverflow.com/a/39715785/8189517

Comment: this is actually really really nice ! leads me in the right direction, thanks !