# Connect to spring backend error

Tags: spring, angular, http, spring-boot

I want try do a Post request from my frontend (Angular 2) to my backend (Spring). But I can't.

The error:

GET http://localhost:8080/loginPost 405 ()

Failed to load http://localhost:8080/loginPost: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://192.168.0.190:4200' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 405.

My Angular Service:

```
import {Injectable} from "@angular/core";
import { Headers, Http } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';
import { Login } from'../data-login/models/login.model';

@Injectable()
export class LoginService{


private loginUrl = 'http://localhost:8080/loginPost';  // URL to web API
private headers = new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/json'});

constructor(private http: Http){}

 loginQuery(login: Login){
   console.log(login.id);
   return this.http.request(this.loginUrl,JSON.stringify(login));
 }
}
```

My Spring Backend Code:

```
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

@RestController
public class LoginProvider {

   @CrossOrigin(origins = "http://192.168.0.190:4200")
   @PostMapping(value="/loginPost", consumes = { MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE })
   public ResponseEntity<?> verifyLogin(@RequestBody String maoe){
       System.out.println(maoe);
       return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.OK);
   }

}
```

I need to read the Json sent by my frontend, checking and responding with OK, no problems. But I can not read Json. I'm trying to store it in the variable "maoe"

Comment: Please post the actual error, not a screenshot of it (some of us have proxies that don't allow imgur)

Comment: zone.js:2935 GET http://localhost:8080/loginPost 405 ()

Failed to load http://localhost:8080/loginPost: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://192.168.0.190:4200' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 405.

Comment: Well it's a CORS issue. **[Find more information here](https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service-cors/)**

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39715785/4078143

Comment: my friends. the problem isn't the connection. I can't read the Json text send from my frontend. But I don't read this. I can response my frontend with OK

Comment: But error which have posted says it is **CORS** issue.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to do send a **GET** request to a resource that accepts only **POST** requests. That is why you are getting a 405 response. Change either your rest service or angular http service to have both matching request types.