# Angular HttpClient doesn't send POST, it sends OPTIONS

Tags: angular, spring-security, oauth-2.0, angular5, spring-security-oauth2

Im' newbie using Angular HttpClient (and writting english too)

I have a problem, I'm trying sending HTTP request with POST method in order to negociate OAuth token obtenction but angular sends OPTIONS request:

*Service:*

```
login(username: string, password: string) {
const body = `username=${encodeURIComponent(username)}&password=${encodeURIComponent(password)}&grant_type=password`;

const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'Authorization': 'Basic ' + btoa(TOKEN_AUTH_USERNAME + ':' + TOKEN_AUTH_PASSWORD)
  })
};  


return this.http.post<string>(AuthenticationService.AUTH_TOKEN, body, httpOptions);
```

*Result:*

[image]

For my backend, I'm using Spring Security and i added a filter to allow CORS:

```
@Bean
public FilterRegistrationBean corsFilter() {
    UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
    CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();
    config.setAllowCredentials(true);
    config.addAllowedOrigin("*");
    config.addAllowedHeader("*");
    config.addAllowedMethod("*");
    source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", config);
    FilterRegistrationBean bean = new FilterRegistrationBean(new CorsFilter(source));
    bean.setOrder(0);
    return bean;
}
```

Comment: it seems that your auth serveur is not on the same domain as your front end application and you are facing CORS(Cross-origin resource sharing) problem.

Comment: You cannot call the `/token` endpoint using XHR. It's supposed to be accessed from backend or a native application.

Comment: Will you serve your angular application from spring too, or will users download scripts from some other domain?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It is not angular related, it is your browser doing.

[Check this issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/7445).

I assume your server runs at localhost:8080, and your angular application at localhost:4200. Since, your request is a cross origin request, browser first sends an `OPTIONS` request to see if it is safe. At this point, your server returns a response with http code 401 which prevents the post request from being made. 
Either you have to do some config in your server or you can use webpack proxy. This is just for your local machine. If you serve your bundled angular application from your server, then you won’t have to do anything for production. I’ve been using this technique for quite some time, and it works just fine.

Example,

Users access my angular application from mydomain.com/ng-app
I also serve my rest api from same domain, mydomain.com/api

So my application always make the request to the server it’s being served from which causes no problem in production.

For latter, you can do following

Create a `proxy.conf.json` at the root of your project (next to `package.json`)
And put following inside

```
{
    "/api/": {
        "target": "http://localhost:8080",
        "secure": false,
        "changeOrigin": true
    }
}
```

In package.json, edit your `start` script and make it `ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.json`

Also, from your frontend, do not send the requests to localhost:8080 directly, instead just write something like `http.post('/api/getSomeData')` which will make the request to localhost:4200 which will redirect it to localhost:8080. This way, you won't have to deal with CORS.

Comment: that won't work if he is deploying this in production or on a server like apache or nginx

Comment: If he is serving angular application from the same domain, it’ll work just fine.

Comment: assuming he uses webpack, it would work but if he was deploying this with some other than webpack then issue comes

Comment: It is not about webpack. When you make request without mentioning the domain, it’ll make the request to the domain which serves the front end application. I’ve been doing the same thing with my project, and it works just fine

Comment: please see [link](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/master/docs/documentation/stories/proxy.md) because you run `ng serve <blah>` it uses webpack to run a development server to serve your angular application. Again if OP uses apache/nginx in a production setting this won't do.

Comment: For me I had to add some more parameters to the config. See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42263440/5298706

Comment: Special note: proxy setup for the current version of Angular (7 or 8) can be done without changing the start script in package.json.  proxy.conf.json setup is the same however you can add [proxyConfig: "proxy.conf.json"] into the "serve/options" section of the angular.json file.  See this link in Angular docs https://angular.io/guide/build#proxying-to-a-backend-server.

Comment: Thanks a ton! This is by far the best answer with proper explanation and code example. THANK YOU!

Answer (score 2):

The `OPTIONS` request is sent first because of `CORS`, Angular needs permission from your backend in order to know if it can `POST`. So on your backend you need to enable `CORS` in order for the http request to go.

Answer (score 0):

For spring boot application, to enable cors request, use @CrossOrigin(origins = "*", maxAge = 3600) on your respective controller.

[Refer this](https://spring.io/blog/2015/06/08/cors-support-in-spring-framework)

Answer (score 0):

use angular cli configuration 
https://angular.io/guide/build#proxying-to-a-backend-server

Answer (score 0):

With a NestJS/Express backend, I fixed this by enabling CORS: https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/security#cors

Answer (score -1):

Finally I found the mistake. 
The order of the Filter there weren't correct. I adjusted it to `Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE` this way it override Spring filter.

```
@Bean
public FilterRegistrationBean corsFilter() {
    UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
    CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();
    config.setAllowCredentials(true);
    config.addAllowedOrigin("*");
    config.addAllowedHeader("*");
    config.addAllowedMethod("*");
    source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", config);
    FilterRegistrationBean bean = new FilterRegistrationBean(new CorsFilter(source));
    bean.setOrder(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE);
    return bean;
}
```

Comment: Be careful though, you are allowing CORS which may result in security flaws.

Comment: Of course, this bean only apply in Development Enviroment

Comment: Check my answer, you would not need this bean even in development environment.

Comment: Using your proxy, Angular made a prefligth request and my backend block it. It answer don't work for me.