# Angular 4 configure a proxy for multiple domains

Tags: angular

I have added a proxy for a domain in the following way using Angular4,

```
/admin/rest/v1.0/pays/pay?sort=regTimeStamp,desc
```

And i have created the `proxy.config.json` in the root of the project folder.

```
{
    "/admin/*" : {
    "target": "https://uat.global.com:8080",
    "secure": false,
    "logLevel": "debug",
    "changeOrigin": true
  }
```

But how do i set proxy for multiple domains?

i want to use two different domain names for different API calls,

1. https://uat.global.com:8080/admin/rest/v1.0/pays/pay?sort=regTimeStamp,desc
2. https://uats.global.com:8081/admin/rest/v1.0/upi/call?sort=regTimeStamp,desc

Comment: Try bypass proxy functionality. https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/master/docs/documentation/stories/proxy.md

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
 "start": "ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.js --base-href /"
```

In proxy.conf.js (not json!):

```
 const PROXY_CONFIG = {
     "/api/*": {
         target: https://www.mydefaulturl.com,
         router: function (req) {
             // some condition here
             var target = 'https://www.myrewrittenurl.com'; // or some custom code
             return target;
         },
         changeOrigin: true,
         secure: false
     }
 };

 module.exports = PROXY_CONFIG;
```

Similar to https://stackoverflow.com/a/45666176/6528560