# Implementation of Proxy Server in Angular4-5

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular5

**Problem Statement:** Client/UI developed using angular-cli and Angular-5, **UI** is running on **http://localhost:4200** and we have **back-end server** running on **http://localhost:8000** that means all api's called like http://localhost:8000/users/getuserinfo and returns some json data properly. Also having other routes like **http://localhost:8000/student/getresult** etc.

So i have to create proxy for this as when i run `ng serve` my application open-up in browser on http://localhost:4200, but while making call to api's url forms like http://localhost:4200/users/getuserinfo which return result like 404 i.e. not found, but when i hit url in another tab for http://localhost:8000/users/getuserinfo, it returns me json data.

So i need to create proxy for http://localhost:4200/users/getuserinfo to like as http://localhost:8000/users/userinfo. I tried to implement using [DOCS](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserver-proxy) but not succeeded and also dont know how get all apis in proxy.conf.json file, can some one help me here?

Below is my code,

```
{
   "/users/userinfo": {
   "target": "http://localhost:8000",
   "secure": false
   }
}
```

Comment: *"not sucedded"* isn't much of a [mcve]. Maybe see https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-proxy

Comment: Possible duplicate of [angular-cli server - how to proxy API requests to another server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37172928/angular-cli-server-how-to-proxy-api-requests-to-another-server)

Comment: See here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37172928/angular-cli-server-how-to-proxy-api-requests-to-another-server

Comment: @Vinod Hope you are aware that The proxy configuration is intended to proxy calls when running the dev server via `ng serve`. After you run `ng build` you are responsible for the web server and its configurations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a proxy file for your api and start the server with this command:

```
ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.json
```

proxy.conf.json

```
{
  "/users": {
    "target": "http://localhost:8000",
    "secure": false
  }
}
```

I find that it is easier to prefix all my api routes with `/api`. This makes it easier when serving the application in production because you can return the app on all routes that don't begin with `/api` and it makes the proxy config just as simple because you only need to setup one rule as opposed to potentially multiple using your current stategy.

Comment: thanks, it helps. Below is my proxy.conf.json file `{
  "/users": {
    "target": "http://localhost:8000",
    "secure": false
  },
  "/student": {
    "target": "http://localhost:8000",
    "secure": false
  },
  ...
  ...
  ...
}`