# The request has to be a valid CORS request and needs to include an "Origin" header. Angular

Tags: angular, laravel, cors, lumen

I have a Laravel/Lumen backend with CORS issues. To solve them, I'm using this package: https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-cors

When I make a request, it works when I download any cors toggle extensions that are out there. In my understanding, that means CORS works on my server but I need to add something to angular to make it fully working. As the developer states on github: "The request has to be a valid CORS request and needs to include an "Origin" header"

Can I add this header in any way?
Thanks in advance

Comment: This is normally handled by the browser, so you should not need to add anything client side. More about CORS here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS

Comment: Well I might have forgotten to mention that it's for an Cordova app, which loads angular.

Comment: So when you debug your app's webview, you do NOT see the Origin header?

Answer (score 0):

You should also add the cors headers in your angularjs request.

for example

```
                    $http({

                        method: 'POST',

                        data: data,

                        url: " url of post request",

                         withCredentials: false,

                         headers: {
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' : "url of laravel",
                        'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'POST',
                        'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' : false
                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I've fought with a similar issue on a few fronts. The best solution I found is to implement a proxy.conf.json config file that does the routing, instead of directly messing with CORS. You implement it using

```
    ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.json
```

This keeps the CORS valid without any plugins on your browser or otherwise. I moved away from CORS plugins because I was forgetting to turn them off when 'surfing in the wild', which left me exposed to hacks.

You can read more on how to implement this solution at [this stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37172928/angular-cli-server-how-to-proxy-api-requests-to-another-server)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure which header you need to have, but if you want to add some headers to all of your requests you can create custom HttpIntercetor like that:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpEvent, HttpInterceptor, HttpHandler, HttpRequest } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';

@Injectable()
export class HttpCustomInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  constructor() { }

  intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    const authRequest = request.clone({
      setHeaders: {
        Origin: 'WhateverYouWantTo'
      }
    });

    return next.handle(authRequest);
  }
}
```

If you want to do it only for some specific requests, i.e. `GET` then you can put some if statement inside `intercept` method. And then use `HttpCustomInterceptor` as a provider for `HTTP_INTERCEPTOR` inside your module:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    HttpClientModule
  ],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
      useClass: HttpClientInterceptor,
      multi: true,
    }
  ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you use nginx as a backend you can solve this problem by adding these headers at the server configuration:

```
location ~ \.php$ {
    [...]
    add_header "Access-Control-Allow-Origin"   * always;
    add_header "Access-Control-Allow-Methods"  "GET, POST, DELETE, PUT, OPTIONS, HEAD" always;
    add_header "Access-Control-Allow-Headers"  "DNT, User-Agent, X-Requested-With, If-Modified-Since, Cache-Control, Content-Type, Range, Authorization, Origin, Accept, Accept-Language" always;
    add_header "Access-Control-Expose-Headers" "Content-Length,Content-Range" always;
}
```

The Access-Control-Allow-Origin header specify the domain to accept requests from.
You can use your domain URL or * to accept requests from any domain.
If you use multiple subdomains for frontend you should use * and block access at the application level.