# Angular reverse proxy behind a corporate proxy

Tags: angular, proxy

I'm try run a angular reverse proxy to request a API as if it were localhost, but i'm behind a corporate proxy.

I created a proxy.conf.json file

```
{
  "/api/*": {
    "target": "http://104.43.135.128:8000",
    "secure": false,
    "changeOrigin": true,
    "logLevel": "debug",
    "pathRewrite": {"^/api" : ""}
  }
}
```

and i'm run angular with npm start (I modified the package.json)

```
"start": "ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.json",
```

¿Does anyone know how i canconfigure a corporate proxy in angular?

I have this error.

```
[HPM] Error occurred while trying to proxy request
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [angular-cli server - how to proxy API requests to another server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37172928/angular-cli-server-how-to-proxy-api-requests-to-another-server)

Comment: it's similar but he is not behind a corporate proxy

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried to do what is descibed in the [documentation](https://angular.io/guide/build#using-corporate-proxy)

```sh
npm install --save-dev https-proxy-agent
```

Create proxy.js

```js
var HttpsProxyAgent = require('https-proxy-agent');
var proxyConfig = [{
  context: '/api',
  target: 'http://104.43.135.128:8000',
  secure: false,
  changeOrigin: true,
  pathRewrite: { "^/api": ""}
}];

function setupForCorporateProxy(proxyConfig) {
  var proxyServer = process.env.http_proxy || process.env.HTTP_PROXY;
  if (proxyServer) {
    var agent = new HttpsProxyAgent(proxyServer);
    console.log('Using corporate proxy server: ' + proxyServer);
    proxyConfig.forEach(function(entry) {
      entry.agent = agent;
    });
  }
  return proxyConfig;
}

module.exports = setupForCorporateProxy(proxyConfig);
```

And run angular with `npm start` ( modify the package.json)

```
"start": "ng serve --proxy-config proxy.js",
```

Comment: Works like a charm. This should be the accepted answer.