# ng-serve proxy config option not working as intended

Tags: proxy, angular5, angular-cli

Starting server as

`ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.json`

the content of prox.conf.json

```
{
  "/api": {
    "target": "http://url.com",
    "secure": false,
    "pathRewrite": {"^/api" : ""}
  }
}
```

I'm, sure the `proxy.conf.json` file is been picked up, cause if I give wrong file path it errors out, but when the server starts, in the log there is no `Proxy created: /api  ->` type message logs ... Why ? Also the proxy not working as apis are getting 404.

N.B.

this is `ng serve` server log

```
ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.json
** Angular Live Development Server is listening on localhost:4200, open your browser on http://localhost:4200/ **

Date: 2019-01-22T20:55:01.248Z
Hash: 5d28d291a6df6ed34917
Time: 9615ms
chunk {main} main.js, main.js.map (main) 30.3 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {polyfills} polyfills.js, polyfills.js.map (polyfills) 236 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {runtime} runtime.js, runtime.js.map (runtime) 6.08 kB [entry] [rendered]
chunk {styles} styles.js, styles.js.map (styles) 179 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {vendor} vendor.js, vendor.js.map (vendor) 6.51 MB [initial] [rendered]
ℹ ｢wdm｣: Compiled successfully.
```

Comment: Try https://stackoverflow.com/a/42263440/1688959

Comment: Can you provide us how your services are being called?

Answer (score 0):

I tried with the following configuration.

```
   {
      "/api": {
        "target": "http://url.com",
        "secure": false,
        "changeOrigin": true
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

```
{
  "/api": {
    "target": "http://api.yourdomain.com",
    "secure": false,
    "changeOrigin": true,
    "logLevel": "info" 
  }
}
```