# Multi sub domain host creation for angular 6 application

Tags: angular

I am trying run the angular application xyz.local insted of [http://localhost:4200][1] and wants to run multi domain concept also.

EX: I want to create xyz.local as the main host 
and want to create sub domains like a.xyz.local,b.xyz.local

my main domain is : test.local
my sub domains will be : a.test.local,b.test.local,c.test.local

how do i create test.local with port in local and how do i create sub-domains like a.test.local,b.test.local,c.test.local etc..

Any solutions?.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [angular-cli server - how to proxy API requests to another server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37172928/angular-cli-server-how-to-proxy-api-requests-to-another-server)

Comment: Both are different.