# Unable to get the data from the new controllers added when SPAPROXY is enabled

Tags: .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-spa

I have created a project with "ASP.Net core with Angular" template, by default SPA proxy got enabled and the project came with the default controller called "weatherforecast".
When i run the application i am getting the screen like below which eventually navigates to the URL(URL2) mentioned in the message from the main URL(URL1) and the application is working fine with URL2.

[image]

Issue is when i add a new controller i am not able to access that controller using the URL2 which is working for "Weatherforecast" controller. Instead it is working with the main URL(URL1).
Can you help me understand this behaviour of SPA proxy is correct and what we need to do to access all the controllers with one URL endpoint.

Comment: Did you add it to your proxy.config.js file ?

Comment: @Carlos Thanks for quick response.  I thought that file is related to angular and i did not add the new routes there. I added it now after your reply and its working fine. Can you please help in understand this proxy concept better.

Comment: This will help you [how-to-proxy-api-requests-to-another-server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37172928/how-to-proxy-api-requests-to-another-server/71764796#71764796)

Comment: @cap29 Thanks for the information. Its working fine for me. But can i use this proxy.config.js if the app is hosted in Azure app service?