Upgrading to Angular 18 with esbuild builder results in CORS errors
We're currently trying to upgrade our application to Angular 18 and try the esbuild builder again. We have a woff2 webfont that we serve as part of the build.
Running the migration to switch to esbuild without making additional changes results in the JS/CSS being loaded correctly, but we're seeing CORS errors for the woff2 files.
We alternatively did look into the option to use a proxy and used it in the past, but for that I'd only want to proxy the asset files. With the webpack builder, this proxy configuration had worked.
const PROXY_HOSTNAME = process.env.PROXY_HOSTNAME || 'localhost';

const PROXY_CONFIG = [
  {
    "context": ['/**'],
    "target": `http://${PROXY_HOSTNAME}:3000`,
    "secure": false,
    "timeout": 360000,
    "changeOrigin": true,
  }
];

Is there a guide on how to transfer this to work with esbuild builder? In the end, I want to serve only the build assets, all other requests are being served by the backend server.

It would be helpful if you posted your error. Changing the builder does not inherently change the deployment server of your assets.

@Sergey The error is a simple CORS error when you try to access the proxied assets from the main Rails server: Access to font at 'http://localhost:4200/media/openproject-icon-font.woff2' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Is your proxy conf file referenced in your serve configuration in your angular.json file? And also are you sure that PROXY_CONFIG is correct? I've always seen config being an object {path1: proxyConfForPath1, path2: proxyConf2} and not a list https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37172928/how-to-proxy-api-requests-to-another-server

Hi @Grogu, this proxy configuration is working fine in Angular 17 currently, and is correctly referenced in angular.json. I'll take a look a the object notation instead.

Proxy only affects requests made by the HttpClient. Is there anything specific about your setup that you serve the app from one port, but request assets from another?

@Sergey no that's not correct, the proxy results in requests matched by the config to be rewritten to the backend server. Of course this also applies to httpClient, but this applies to all other non-assets requests

Fonts are assets.

When you reference the font file on the css is it showing which url?
